# What assumptions do we need for Fourier transform of derivative formula

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose $f: \mathbb R \to\mathbb C$ is differentiable and $f$ and $f'$ are in $L^1(\mathbb R)$. Do we need further assumptions to have the formula:

$$\widehat{f'}(t) = (2\pi it)\hat f(t) $$

My textbook also assumes $f$ is continuously differentiable which I don't see why it is needed. Basically we want the limit of $f(x)$ to be zero when $x \to +$ or $- \infty$ which we can prove using the fundamental theorem of calculus, no?

Comment: if $f'$ is (piecewise) continuous, no problem for writing $\int_{-A}^A f'(t) e^{-2 i \pi \xi t} dt = f(A) e^{-2 i \pi \xi A}-f(-A) e^{2 i \pi \xi A} + 2 i \pi \xi\int_{-A}^A f(t) e^{-2 i \pi \xi t} dt$. if $f',f \in L^1$  then $\int_{-A}^A f'(t) e^{-2 i \pi \xi t} dt $ and $\int_{-A}^A f'(t) e^{-2 i \pi \xi t} dt $ converge as $A \to \infty$, and it must exist a sequence $|A_n| \to \infty$ such that $f(\pm A_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ (because otherwise $f $ cannot be $\in L^1$)

Comment: so that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(t) e^{-2 i \pi \xi t} dt  = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-A_n}^{A_n} f'(t) e^{-2 i \pi \xi t} dt = 2 i \pi \xi\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-2 i \pi \xi t} dt$$

Comment: @user1952009 what would be the problem if $f'$ was not piecewise continuous?

Comment: $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$  $\Leftrightarrow$ $g$ is piece continuous on $[a,b]$

Comment: @user1952009 I don't know much, but are you sure about the equivalence? I don't think it is necessary for riemann integrable functions to be piecewise continuous

Comment: you mean improper Riemann integrable. and what you need to understand is that those are sufficient condition such that everything works perfectly well, it doesn't mean in other cases it will fail. (defining the cases for which it will fail is much more complicated)

Comment: @user1952009 what I am understanding is that we need continuous (piecewise) differentiability to be able to integrate the thing with $f'$ by parts. so you are saying that to integrate by parts we need piecewise continuity of both functions. is that right?

Comment: Bananach: you're spot-on. Consider the function $f$ that's nonzero only on numbers of the form $x = \frac{n}{2^k}$ in lowest terms ($n$ an integer, $k$ a nonnegative integer) with $f(x) = \frac{1}{2^k}$, is integrable, but discontinuous at all the places where it's nonzero. So integrable doesn't imply piecewise continuous.

Comment: if $f'(t)$ is (piecewise) continuous, then $f(t) = \int f'(t) dt$ is (piecewise) $C^1$. the notation $f'$ is confusing. start with $g(t)$ instead of $f'$, and $f(t) = C+\int_0^t g(u) du$

Comment: On the interval $[0,1]$, the integral is zero. Clearly that's the lower sum for any partition. For upper sums, refine any partition by placing points to the left and right of $2^{-k}$, at a distance of, say, $2^{-k-s}$ (for some $s$). Then the upper sum for the interval containing $n/2^k$ is at most $2^{-k-s}*2^{-k}$. There are at most $2^k$ such intervals in the unit interval, so the sum is no more than $2^{-k-s}$. Summing this over all nonneg $k$ gives at most $2^{-s}$. Picking $s$ large makes this arbitrarily small. So...the integral's zero.

Comment: If you don't trust me, see Spivak's *Calculus*, exercise 13-34: "Let $f(x)$ be 0 for irrational $x$ and $1/q$ if $x = p/q$ in lowest terms. Show that $f$ is integrable on $[0, 1]$, ..."  That function upper-bounds the one I described, so...

Comment: @JohnHughes : do you think it is the subject here ? I have a simple discussion on : your theorem defines the conditions such that everything is easy to prove, and you come with functions being zero on the irrationals non zero on the rationals... come on

Comment: why not a function assuming the axiom of choice since you want to extend the Riemann integral to everything ?

Comment: @user1952009 Since the question asks for weaker conditions so that the equation holds, it's important to see how the notations can be generalized.    Moreover, since you claimed an incorrect statement in the comment, it is important that someone point it out so that no one will be misguided.

Comment: @JohnMa : no, his question is "I don't understand why we assume those conditions on $f',f$". it is not "what are the larger conditions such that it holds" (and no the answer is not : look at the Fourier transform of tempered distributions...)

Comment: I know this because he didn't write the proof I wrote, and he didn't get that $f \in L^1 \implies$ the integration by parts is simpler

Comment: My question is whether we need further conditions than "$f$ is differentiable, $f$ and $f'$ in $L^1(R)$" and why continuous differentiability is necessary as written in my textbook. So basically I'm asking if only differentiability is sufficient and if not then why do we need to have continuous differentiablity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum set of conditions needed can be expressed using the Lebesgue integral. Essentially you need $f$ to be absolutely continuous with derivative $f' \in L^1$. Absolutely continuous means $f$ is the integral of its derivative:
$$
              f(y)-f(x)=\int_{x}^{y}f'(t)dt.
$$
This all works out very nicely using the Lebesgue integral.

For the Riemann integral, you could assume that $f \in L^1$, and that there exists $g\in L^1$ such that
$$
               f(y)-f(x)=\int_{x}^{y}g(t)dt,\;\;\; x,y \in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Using the Riemann integral, you're more or less stuck with assuming that $g$ is Riemann integrable on every finite interval. You could allow a few isolated singularities by employing an improper Riemann integral, but that's about the least you can get away with, if you're going to use the Riemann integral. And it's enough to imply that
$$
            \widehat{f'}(s)=2\pi is\widehat{f}(s),\;\;\; s\in\mathbb{R},
$$
assuming the proper normalization for the Fourier transform.